# Calculadora Gráfica em JS Puro com o Uso do FOR

Tags: javascript

Olá, pessoal!! Sou super iniciante em JS e recebi como desafio, num nivelamento para estágio, criar uma calculadora gráfica em JS puro através do uso do laço FOR. Pesquisei, mas só achei com uso de biblioteca (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQh40y9KqrI). Gostaria que alguém fizesse a gentileza de me ajudar, se possível com uma dica bem rudimentar. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Gostaria que alguém me ajudasse a criar um código em JS puro, com o uso do laço FOR, capaz de gerar gráficos com base na função Y = 2x + 1, onde o usuário indicaria diversos valores de x. Grato pela atenção.